# Image slider html css

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create this image slider. Which language/template/js/code is the best to use? I was thinking about slick, but I think it can be easier?

[image]

Comment: [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) Or [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Comment: Bootstrap carousel will save you a bunch of time!

Comment: @Marty , Only if they had a carousel that looked exactly like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code without using any library

Just change the image URL to your image

Doing something without any library is the best practise for performance

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Slideshow Gallery</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/in/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/_jcr_content/main-pars/image.img.jpg/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_1000x560.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
    
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/in/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/_jcr_content/main-pars/image.img.jpg/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_1000x560.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help! When I want 7 images in the "bottom bar" the images get out of the bar and became large, any idea?

Comment: For that, you'll have to create a slider for that section too , so that you can have unlimited bottom images

Comment: what is the max? 6?

Comment: Nothing like that, If you can reduce the size of the image then you can fit it how much ever possible , But if you create a slider then you can fit in 100's of image

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
<p>Change image every 10 seconds:</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/640?image=990" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/640?image=991" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/640?image=992" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
```